# Setting same height on columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am making a row with 2 columns with Bootstrap 3. I am programming for a webshop there is having around 100.000 products, so it is not converted to BS4 yet. Therefore I am forced to use BS3. The left column is gonna contain a background color and some text, while the right column will be an image.

**This is how the row is looking like now:**

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3" style="background-color:pink;">
            <h3>Headline</h3>
            <p>Some text here</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <img src="http://placehold.it/900x200">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**This is how my end result should be:**
[image]

Comment: This works for me on codepen, and by changing sm to md, it works locally too

Comment: Hey Singh. On my computer it is looking like this: https://imgur.com/UjLI0F4. So the columns are not having equal height?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments your code is working, since you are using bootstrap 3 you may want to use `img-responsive` class for your image, because it has a large width.

By the way I have changed your `col-sm-3` and `col-sm-9` classes to `xs` ones, you may want to consider changing them to `md` or `sm` for your case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-HSMxcRTRxnN+Bdg0JdbxYKrThecOKuH5zCYotlSAcp1+c8xmyTe9GYg1l9a69psu"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <style>
      .d-flex {
        display: flex;
      }
      .image-container {
        background-size: cover;
        background-position: center center;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>
      This is a static template, there is no bundler or bundling involved!
    </h1>
  </body>
  <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="row d-flex">
        <div class="col-xs-3" style="background-color:pink;">
          <h3>Headline</h3>
          <p>Some text here</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Button</button>
        </div>
        <div
          class="col-xs-9 image-container"
          style="background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/287/900/200)"
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
</html>
```

-Edit: after taking a deeper look on what you really want to achieve (same height for both columns) I *updated* my question with the follow:

Adding a class called `d-flex` to set a `display: flex` on any container you need, once a container has a `display: flex;` value its children will stretch by default.
You may also need to update your image to support a `height: 100%` which I highly recommend not to, cause it will make the image look ugly. Instead take advantage of `background-size: cover;`.

Some good resources on how to make your image fit in nicely:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/background-size/

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I am running my code it is looking like this: https://imgur.com/UjLI0F4. So the height on the columns are not equal?

Comment: Thank you a lot for your help. I can see what you mean, that the image is looking weird. I would really really like to see your suggestion, regarding setting the background-size instead. Do you have time for making an example with this?

Comment: Thank you a lot the help Shahbazi. But then you have to set a height on the col?

Comment: No you don't need to set a height for columns if you are using `display: flex` on the container, since the columns will stretch by default